# Add a menu icon for each of the menu items in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a menu icon for each of the menu items in  WordPress from the admin side. I don't want to use the CSS, instead I must be able to upload the image from the navigation admin. I am using Walker_Nav_Menu to add description to the menu items. Is it possible to add an icon to the menu item from the admin side using this class? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I used this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/nav-menu-images/ and modified it using this tutorial http://blog.milandinic.com/2012/11/23/nav-menu-images-developers-guide/